# postgresql group column to json include array

Tags: json, postgresql

table_name e

```
id | name | cate | link  
---+------+------+---------
1  | a    |  A   | link1
2  | a    |  B   | link2
3  | a    |  B   | link3
4  | b    |  B   | link4
5  | c    |  A   | link5
6  | d    |  A   | link6
7  | e    |  B   | link7
```

I want retults:

```
name | A                        | B
------+------+-------------------+------------
a    |  {id: 1, link: 'link1'}  | [{id: 2, link: 'link2'}, {id: 3, link: 'link3'}]
b    |                          | [{id: 4, link: 'link4'}]
c    |  {id: 5, link: 'link5'}  |
d    |  {id: 6, link: 'link6'}  |
e    |                          | [{id: 7, link: 'link7'}]
```

The cate field value only A,B,C,D. but value is B must an array

my experiment was a failure

```
select name, format('{%s}', string_agg(format('"id": "%s", "name": "%s", "link":"%s"', id, name, link), ','))::json as A from elements where cate = 'A' group by name;
select name, string_to_array(format('[link: "%s", id: "%s", name: "%s"]', link, id, name)) as B from elements where cate = 'B' group by name;
select name, format('{%s}', string_agg(format('"id": "%s", "name": "%s", "link":"%s"', id, name, link), ','))::json as C from elements where cate = 'C' group by name;
select name, format('{%s}', string_agg(format('"id": "%s", "name": "%s", "link":"%s"', id, name, link), ','))::json as D from elements where cate = 'D' group by name;
```

If join other table p

```
id | e_id | role_id 
---+------+----------
1  | 1    |  100
2  | 3    |  101
3  | 4    |  102
4  | 5    |  103
```

results:

```
name   | checked | A                                     | B
-------+---------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
a      |   true  | {id: 1, link: 'link1', checked: true} | [{id: 2, link: 'link2'}, {id: 3, link: 'link3', checked: true}]
b      |   true  |                                       | [{id: 4, link: 'link4', checked: true}]
c      |   true  | {id: 5, link: 'link5', checked: true} |
d      |         | {id: 6, link: 'link6'}                |
e      |         |                                       | [{id: 7, link: 'link7'}]
```

Comment: What is wrong with your attempts? Do you get an error? Incorrect result? if yes, which?

Comment: Post postgresql version

Comment: @JustMe 9.4+ and I'm trying which, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use format function to create json fields, PostgreSQL has all the function you need to parse and create json field. You didn't post sample ddl and data but your query should look like this:

```
select name, 
   json_agg(case cate when 'A' then json_build_object('id',id,'link',link) end) A, 
   json_agg(case cate when 'B' then json_build_object('id',id,'link',link) end) B 
from data group by name
```

Comment: field A should be return json.